# Dompdf Create a A4 page with 4 equals parts

Tags: html, css, height, dompdf

I try to create a A4 page with 4 parts.

There is a white separator between the 2 first squares and the it breaks the page at square 3.

And quite strange the image does not appear in square 3!

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Header and Footer example</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    @page {
      margin: 0;
    }
    .pages {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .dis-inl-blc  {
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:top;
    }
    .page-break {
      page-break-after: always;
    }
    .center {
      text-align:center;
    }
    .bg-red {
      background:red;
    }
    .bg-green {
      background:green;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
         <div class="pages page-break">
              <div class="dis-inl-blc center bg-red" style="margin-left:-0.03in;width:50%;height:50%;padding-top:5%;">
                  <img src="'.$image2Base64.'" style="height:2.5in"><br>Square 1
              </div>
              <div class="dis-inl-blc center bg-green" style="margin-right:-0.03in;width:50%;height:50%;padding-top:5%;">
                  <img src="'.$image2Base64.'" style="height:2.5in"><br>Square 2
              </div>
              <div class="dis-inl-blc center bg-green" style="margin-left:-0.03in;width:50%;height:50%;padding-top:5%;">
                  <img src="'.$image2Base64.'" style="height:2.5in"><br>Square 3
              </div>
              <div class="dis-inl-blc center bg-red" style="margin-right:-0.03in;width:50%;height:50%;padding-top:5%;">
                  <img src="'.$image2Base64.'" style="height:2.5in"><br>Square 4
              </div>
          </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The PHP part is quite basic:

```
$options = new \Dompdf\Options();
$options->set('isRemoteEnabled', true);
$options->set('isPhpEnabled', true);
$dompdf = new \Dompdf\Dompdf($options);
$dompdf->set_option('dpi', 300);
$dompdf->set_paper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$output = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents('test.pdf', $output);
```

***NOTE***

I also tried with tables but with same issue.

```
<table class="bg-red" style="width:100%;line-height:0;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
  <td class="bg-grey" style="width:50%;height:50%;line-height:0;">Square 1</td>
  <td class="bg-green" style="width:50%;height:50%;line-height:0;">Square 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="bg-green" style="width:50%;height:50%;line-height:0;">Square 3</td>
  <td class="bg-grey" style="width:50%;height:50%;line-height:0;">Square 4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIqek.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFpMs.png